# Alternative power source or bypass altogether?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, adapter

I need to replace this 20+ year AC/AC 7.5VAC (4.0MM x 1.7MM FEMALE) adapter, but can not find it anywhere.
I'm looking for advice on what may work in its place, or if there's a way to bypass it altogether to provide power in a different way.

Also, I did find a 7.5VAC AC/AC wall transformer plug, but with only 300mA and the wrong sized connector tip.... would the 300mA work if I can figure out a way to switch the connecter?

My knowledge on electronics is extremely limited, so please please explain in as simple terms as possible.
I would be extremely appreciative of any help/advice you could provide.

EDIT: thanks everyone. The adapter powers an older dept56 christmas village animated piece.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is it powering? That's an uncommon voltage so if there's some flexibility that might be helpful.

Comment: 300mA *might* work - if the existing adapter is oversized for its application. What are you powering with it?

Comment: Brhans, it does help some, but it seems to be mainly focused on AC/DC power. I'm not sure if the same rules apply to a device which works on an old AC/AC wall plug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy any AC transformer that fit your needs without considering the connector (try to take one identical or with a slightly higher current). Then either find the right barrel jack or cut the old one with some wire and install it on your new transformer.

Comment: Thank you Julien!  I found a barrel jack that's the correct size, but it's labeled as DC... "4.0mm x 1.7mm Female DC Power Adapter Cable".  Do you know if it matters that it's labeled DC if I'm just using the barrel? Or am I supposed to find a jack labeled as AC?

Comment: Not it shouldn't matter! Many less professional retailers place many insignificant term to pop in searches. I wouldn't worry. The important part is really the outside and inside diameter. The only difference I might think is if it has a metal housing, it could pass DC certification and not AC one but I doubt it will be the case!